# What is needed to repair a garage drain cover in concrete?

Tags: plumbing, concrete, drain

Our garage is a concrete slab on grade with a floor drain in the center. I intend to use this space as a workshop with a desk and need to repair the rusted out drain / drain cover to be flush with the floor but am unsure what is needed. I have tried to research the drain assembly but am not finding information on what drain is currently in place, or how I would remove it. It appears the square flange that has deteriorated around the perimeter is connected to the drain basin. If I can get the square flange out I think I could just find a square drain cover to replace, but I am unsure if removing the flange would result in needing to replace more.

Essentially I am looking for information on what the flange is connected to, how the assembly is probably attached to the concrete (is it just sitting on the concrete, is it glued down, or is it connected to the pipe that runs under the concrete?) to understand what I need to do to get a flat top surface. As a workshop there will be limited to no water or liquids going down the drain but I also don't want to destroy it unnecessarily.

Image of the drain showing the rusted out square flange (half missing, but the other half does not lift up). Flange is 8.5" square.

[image: Image of the drain showing the rusted out square flange (half missing, but the other half does not lift up)]

Comment: Step zero - vacuum up the loose crud, then stick a hose in the hole, turn  it on, and see if it drains or not. Take a look around the outside to see if there's any evidence of where it drains to.

Comment: Is it just me, or does that not look round?

Answer (score 1):

The drain was originally just embedded in the concrete. The cover fastened to it. I see a few paths forward:

1. Assume that the pipe itself is in as bad of shape as the drain. Plug it with sand, filling the top few inches with cement, then overlay vinyl concrete patch to finish the floor smoothly.
2. Properly replace the drain. Open the concrete enough to work, cut the pipe at a sensible location, and rebuild it using a shielded no-hub coupler and new plastic drain. Repair the concrete (which isn't terribly difficult, in case that intimidates you).
3. Fasten a new grille directly to the concrete (after removing all interfering components with a grinder). The old one probably screwed into the drain bowl, but that's no longer viable. Find a stainless grate that's the right size, or cut one from a larger part. Use plastic plug anchors so you can easily remove it for cleaning or whatever.